# Ruby: cross-platform way to determine whether NFS is installed?

Tags: ruby, package, nfs

I need to detect whether NFS is installed or not on the running server in my Ruby code.

If there is any way I can do this in cross-platform way(or at least in unix/linux)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NFS - Network File System

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  I don't know any Unix systems that don't have NFS in the kernel but specific driver information isn't usually accessed by the application.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to solve this problem  in open source project - https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues#issue/135

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a cross platform way to do it as there's no standards for getting kernel info.  I think it would have to be specific to the guest OS type.  Linux you could do "modinfo nfs".  Solaris boxes you could also use modinfo and search for nfs in the output or look in /etc/dfs/fstypes.   Using "uname -s" will tell you which method to use.